# Mono on Unix - File system ACLs

Tags: c#, unix, mono, acl

Are there methods in Mono C# to interact with file ACLs and extended ACLs?

I found the assembly Mono.Posix.dll, and the class UnixFileInfo.

This can give me nice things like the owner group and user, but no ACLs.

Does it exist?  Or would I have to basically use DllImport for everything?

Comment: The header files to do this in C are in /user/include/sys/acl.h on my system.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution or have succeed to build you own wrapper around the Linux library [libacl.so](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libacl1-dev/index.html)?
I was surprised ACL was not supported  in [Mono.Posix.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/5.20.1-preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `Mono.Posix` has no implementation for ACLs.

And also the namespace `System.Security.AccessControl` is not implemented by Mono.

If you want to change ACLs in Windows, you can create a library (dll) compiled with the .NET framework, using System.Security.AccessControl for do it, and then load it from Mono through reflection.

Here are some resources about how to use `System.Security.AccessControl`:

http://blog.crowe.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/08/25/c---An-example-of-setting-NTFS-Directory--File.aspx

Other alternative using `Microsoft.Win32.Security`:

http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/02/08/69403.aspx

The other alternative is use `DllImport` and call native methods.

Comment: This would be running on Unix only, so looks like DllImport is the only option?